# GridView Column DataType as Value of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

Someone here earlier helped me get the code below that populates a dropdownlist with the column names and datatype of a GridView. Now I want the datatype to be the value of the dropdownlist and I'm not sure how to do it.  Can anyone show me how?

```
 public void ddlColumnPopulate()
    {
        var gvColumns = GridView1.Columns;
        var viewName = ((IDataSource)EntityDataSource1).GetViewNames().OfType<string>().First();

        var view = (EntityDataSourceView)((IDataSource)EntityDataSource1).GetView(viewName);
        var schema = view.GetViewSchema();
        var dsColumns = schema.Columns;
        var dvColumnsDict = gvColumns.OfType<BoundField>().ToDictionary(a => a.DataField);

        foreach (DataColumn c in dsColumns)
        {
            var li = new ListItem(string.Format("{0}: {1}", c.ColumnName, c.DataType), c.ColumnName);                
            ddlColumn.Items.Add(li);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured itout.

```
var li = new ListItem(string.Format("{0}: {1}", c.ColumnName, c.DataType), c.DataType.ToString());
```